# Opengl ES android Skeletal animation from JSON file

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to implement skeletal Andriod from a JSON file which is imported from Blender.Anyone knows whether the position,rotation and scale in key frame and Bones represented from the origin or from the root bone?
And how is the angle represented in the JSON file ?

Comment: Well, wouldn't the JSON file format you're using tell you that? Look up the documentation for it.